# Use SQL to determine cost of a rewards scheme

Tags: sql

I have a SQL view that shows customer id, month, and revenue(USD) generated for a retail company, such as below.

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
| CLIENT_ID |   MONTH   | REVENUE_GENERATED |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|    29837  | Jan 2020  |            123362 |
|    12412  | Jan 2020  |              2973 |
|    12412  | Jan 2020  |              1824 |
|    54398  | Mar 2020  |                12 |
|    81724  | Mar 2020  |               436 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

I would like to see the cost (in terms of how revenue much revenue is lost) of  implementing a rewards scheme that provides a discount (proportional to the revenue generated) based on the following tiers and discounts:

```
+--------------+----------+
| REVENUE_TIER | DISCOUNT |
+--------------+----------+
| 0-250        | 0%       |
| 250-1000     | 1%       |
| 1000-2500    | 2%       |
| 2500-5000    | 4%       |
| 5000-10,000  | 6%       |
| >10,000      | 8%       |
+--------------+----------+
```

What is the best way to assess the cost using these informations? **I want to identify the lost amount of revenue per bucket per month.**

I would assume to first create buckets for each tier and count the clients in each bucket per month, then calculate the cost based upon the client count per bucket per month?
i.e. generate this

```
+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+
|  MONTH   | 0-250 | 250-1000 | 1000-2500 | 2500-5000 | 5000-10,000 | >10,000 |
+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+
| Jan 2020 |    99 |       28 |        47 |         5 |          65 |       0 |
| Feb 2020 |   128 |      188 |        17 |        84 |          98 |      47 |
| Mar 2020 |   122 |       67 |        12 |         1 |           1 |       1 |
+----------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+
```

then take the multiply the count by the revenue tier to get cost.

If further clarication is needed I am here to support.

sql code to generate count table:

```
SELECT
   MONTH,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN REVENUE_GENERATED <= 250 THEN 1 END) AS "0-250",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN REVENUE_GENERATED > 250 AND REVENUE_GENERATED <= 1000 THEN 1 END) AS "250-1000",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN RREVENUE_GENERATED > 1000 AND REVENUE_GENERATED <= 2500 THEN 1 END) AS "1000-2500",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN REVENUE_GENERATED > 2500 AND REVENUE_GENERATED <= 5000 THEN 1 END) AS "2500-5000",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN REVENUE_GENERATED > 5000 AND REVENUE_GENERATED <= 10000 THEN 1 END) AS "5000-10000",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN REVENUE_GENERATED > 10000 THEN 1 END) AS "+10000"
FROM
   REVENUE
GROUP BY
   MONTH;
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.  For starters, can you include to your question the queries that you have tried already so far?

Comment: @blurfus Thank you. I have added my query to generate a table. I am unsure how best to apply my idea of using the count of client in tiers to get cost.

Comment: What do you actually want ? The lost amount of revenue per bucket per month ?

Comment: @SvetlinZarev yes the change in revenue per bucket per month.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a common table expression to define the tiers and join it with your revenue results like this:

```
with
    sample (`client_id`, `month`, `revenue`) as (
        select '29837', 'jan 2020', 123362 union all
        select '12412', 'jan 2020', 2973 union all
        select '12412', 'jan 2020', 1824 union all
        select '54398', 'mar 2020', 12 union all
        select '81724', 'mar 2020', 436 
    ),
    tiers (`low`, `high`, `label`, `discount`) as (
        select 0, 249.999, '0-250', 0 union all
        select 250, 999.999, '250-1000', 1 union all
        select 1000, 2499.999, '1000-2500', 2 union all
        select 2500, 5999.999, '2500-5000', 4 union all
        select 5000, 9999.999, '5000-10000', 6 union all
        select 10000, 9999999.999, '>10000', 8
)   
select 
    sample.*, 
    tiers.label, 
    tiers.discount, 
    (revenue * (discount / 100)) revenue_discount
from
    sample 
    join tiers on sample.revenue between tiers.low and tiers.high
```

See this [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eH6yrKPTVvzNXhYSbMPeja/0).

Comment: thank you for providing, how would this be implemented in Oracle? as far as I am aware you cannot define the table within the CTE

Comment: Sure, Oracle supports the WITH clause, that it calls a ['subquery factoring clause'](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF30048), but of course you will need to use DUAL table to build the tiers table on the fly. See this working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d53be99a8e7316892517d7a1738b1e1d) specifically for Oracle. Group by tiers.label and any other column you want to aggregate revenue and calculated discounts.